# Gravitational correction in index theorem for 3+1 time-reversal invariant TI

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-insulators, quantum-anomalies

In Witten's review paper: Fermion path integrals and topological phases, the index theorem for 3+1 $\mathcal{T}$-conserving TI is given by 
$$e^{\mp i\pi \eta/2}e^{\pm i\pi(P-\hat{A}(R))}=(-1)^{\mathcal{I}}$$
where $\eta$ is the eta-invariant of the boundary fermion, $P$ is the U(1) instanton number given by $\frac{e^2}{32\pi^2}\int_X F\wedge F$, and $\hat{A}(R)$ is the gravitational correction with $R$ being the Riemann tensor of the underlying manifold.

In the case of TI, the bulk, denoted by $X$, is considered to be a manifold with boundary, on the other side of which lives the trivial phase. $P$ is not an integer because $X$ has a boundary. Then the paper claims that the combination $\hat{A}(R)-P-\eta/2$ is integer valued. $\eta$ by definition is an integer, which means $\hat{A}-P$ is either integer or half-integer depending on whether $\eta$ is even or odd. Here is my question:

Even though this is the statement of the APS index theorem, I don't have enough math background to fully understand the $\hat{A}$ term. So let's look at a simple physical system: a piece of 3d TI in the non-trivial phase. In this case, we still have a boundary, but I don't see where this Riemann tensor $R$ comes from. The spacetime of this physical system seems perfectly flat.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.